# Is there a way I can code a data set utilising only the first number assigned to an individual?

Tags: r

Bassically I am utilising ringing data for a project im working on and I have been asked to assign a unique ID to each individual. The idea is to use the first ringing number the individual was given, unfortuantely the data has been given in a format which makes using this first number hard. It would basically look like this

| ID Ring Number | Previous ring number |
| --- | --- |
| 7829 | 3340 |
| 5689 | 0 |
| 2543 | 6789 |
| 3340 | 2799 |

So for example despite the latest ring number being 7829, I would want the value 2779 to be used for this unique. I originally tried to have it so if there was a non zero number in the "previous ring number" column the the unique ID would use that. But that doesn't account for an indicidual changing rings multiple times. I would basically like to know is there a way I can use the first ringing number for this unique ID, manually selecting it isn't an option as there are 50,000 entries of data. Im still not too experienced with R so apologies if this is an easy question.

Edit: I have realised a mistake in my attempt to explain how i want the outcome to look like. Essentially a new column (from the unique IDs gathered) added onto this table that would look like this

| ID Ring Number | Previous ring number | Unique ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7829 | 3340 | 2799 |
| 5689 | 0 | 5689 |
| 2543 | 6789 | 6789 |
| 3340 | 2799 | 2799 |

Comment: Can you post what your desired output would look like? I struggle to understand the issue here.

Comment: @TomHoel I have just realised a mistake in how i want the output to be. Instead the column would consist of 2799, 5689, 6789, 2799. As i remembered since its ringing data those are repeat captures of the same individual. So sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `neighborhood` function from `igraph` in `mode = 'out'` to find the ancestor of each ID:

```r
data <- read.table(text="
'ID Ring Number'    'Previous ring number'
7829    3340
5689    0
2543    6789
3340    2799",header=T)

library(igraph)


g <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(data)

neighbors <- igraph::neighborhood(g,nodes=V(g)[match(data$ID,names(V(g)))],  order=vcount(g), mode="out")

ancestors <- lapply(neighbors,function(x) {x[[length(x)]]$name})

data$`Unique ID` <- ancestors

data
#>   ID.Ring.Number Previous.ring.number Unique ID
#> 1           7829                 3340      2799
#> 2           5689                    0         0
#> 3           2543                 6789      6789
#> 4           3340                 2799      2799
```

Comment: That read.table part. Does it require the text part to be typed out in full? Just cos the table i made above was an example of the columns in the data set given. The real data is like 50,000 entries

Comment: I have just realised a mistake in how i want the output to be. Instead the column would consist of 2799, 5689, 6789, 2799. As i remembered since its ringing data those are repeat captures of the same individual. So sorry for the confusion

Comment: `read.table` is to get a running example. you could have used `dput` to supply a part of your data. For the second question, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @stefan, we perhaps have a solution.

Your data

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
     ID Previous
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1  7829     3340
2  5689        0
3  2543     6789
4  3340     2799

df %>%
  mutate(result =
           case_when(Previous %in% ID ~ Previous[match(Previous, ID)],
                     Previous == 0 ~ ID,
                     TRUE ~ Previous))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
     ID Previous result
  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1  7829     3340   2799
2  5689        0   5689
3  2543     6789   6789
4  3340     2799   2799
```

Comment: I though this should be recursive, allowing many levels of IDs. This only works if ID is changed once, but perhaps this is what OP is expecting.

Comment: @Waldi Would that not work with multiple ID changes then? I thought I checked it for that, I'll look again

Comment: Try to add a new line like `2799 1` in test data

Comment: @Waldi Ah you're right. Good shout so how would I make it recursive? Im guessing I have to call the function within itself but where abouts? Sorry I think this is showing I don't understand R as well as I thought

Comment: One of the options is to use `igraph` which handles this automatically